# Having issues w/ JS ScrollTop in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scrolltop

I'm trying to simulate smooth scrolling between panels and add an active state to links when the top of the panel reaches the top of the viewport. Everything was going great until I tested in Firefox. Scrolling between panels is jagged, and the active state is added to the wrong link at times. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.link').each(function (event) {
      if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 0) {
        $('.link').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });
});

// SMOOTH SCROLLING

$(function () {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 0)
        }, 850);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Also you can see the page I'm working on here: http://zebron.github.io/